# Client Id blank in "API Calls Made Within Last 7 Days"-Report

Tags: rest-api, reporting, connected-apps

we have created a connected app, when running the "API Calls Made Within Last 7 Days" - Report, the report doesn't show the name of our app in the column client id (see picture). What do we need to setup to see our app name in that column?

cheers,
Timo
[image]

Comment: I think it might be down to the client to give themselves an ID, I get the same in my DE orgs when using my chosen IDE to write code.

Comment: Good idea, couldn't find anything about it in the REST API documentation, though. I played around defining different XHR headers (pretty much stabbing in the dark) but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client ID / Token is defined when using the SOAP API and goes in the [CallOption.client](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_header_calloptions.htm#calloptions_client). It allows your app to access professional edition orgs via the API. I think Salesforce assigns it to you when you pass certification, but there isn't anything stopping you passing in whatever value you want.

There isn't a direct equivalent for the REST API that will populate the Client Id. Instead you can get you app whitelisted by Salesforce.

> If you have  a partner app you should now be able to get your OAuth
> client whitelisted for api access, talk to your contact in the partner
> group.

Source: [Does the REST API support Client ID?](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_header_calloptions.htm#calloptions_client)

**Update:**
The REST API now supports the [Call Options Header](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_calloptions.htm) that can define the `client`

```
Sforce-Call-Options: client=caseSensitiveToken; defaultNamespace=battle
```

Comment: The REST API should support a similar mechanism from Winter '15 (safe harbor).