# Client Id blank in “API Calls Made Within Last 7 Days” Report - when testing from an Android app

Tags: rest-api, connected-apps, android

We have created an Android app which communicates with the Salesforce via Salesforce Mobile SDK and its APIs. As part of the settings we created a connected app in salesforce, obtained a clientId(consumer_key) and consumer_secret. Now we started using the app which can make a maximum of 1000 API calls in a day.

But whil running the "API Calls Made Within Last 7 Days" - Report, the report doesn't show the name of our connected app in the column client id (see picture). What do we need to setup to see our connected app name in that column? Or how can we differentiate that only our Android app made "n" no. of API calls?

[image]

Comment: Please only use tags specificly related to your question, this will help you attract people with the right knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to the question asked [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21976/client-id-blank-in-api-calls-made-within-last-7-days-report).

The Mobile SDK uses REST API while the client ID / Token is defined only for the SOAP API and goes in the CallOption.client. Unfortunately, there isn't a direct equivalent for the REST API that will populate the Client Id. Instead you can get you app whitelisted by Salesforce.

If you have a partner app you should now be able to get your OAuth client whitelisted for api access, talk to your contact in the partner group.

More details [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_header_calloptions.htm#calloptions_client).

Comment: yes i have seen the question and not satisfied by the answer. Can u provide more info on whitelisting my app in salesforce. My Android app is talking to salesforce via the connected app. It doesn't have any restricted IPs. It is being accessed globally from any location. But i cannot see the clientId popped up in the API usage reports. Android and

Comment: By whitelisting if you mean that i should provide all possible IP ranges in the "Trusted IP Ranges" settings section in salesforce. I have done that already.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. If you have a partner app, you need to get in touch with your Salesforce partner contact to get it whitelisted. In any case, from your response, it seems this is NOT a partner app, so I would actually recommend using external tools such as New Relic/ Flurry which can help you track/ monitor specific Apex API endpoints in terms of number of hits, time taken etc. Hope this helps.